# Changing various date-formats to one format

Tags: php, mysql

So I had this code which was buggy and it saved dates randomly in "**m-d-yyyy**" OR "**mm-dd-yyyy**" OR "**yyyy-mm-dd**" OR "**yyyy-m-d**".

How can I, in a query fetch data from this column so that the date is always in "YYYY-MM-DD" format?

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
DATE_FORMAT(c.tx_date, ('%Y-%m-%d')) as tx_date
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: personally i would write a script to convert the stored db values, rather than doing it on the fly every time

Comment: Do the `m-d` values also interchange, or are there only the 4 cases you've listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use STR_TO_DATE() as the inverse of DATE_FORMAT(). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Here's an example to convert your various formats into a proper YYYY-MM-DD date value:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  STR_TO_DATE(c.tx_date, '%c-%e-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(c.tx_date, '%m-%d-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(c.tx_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
  STR_TO_DATE(c.tx_date, '%Y-%c-%e')) AS tx_date
...
```

You should always avoid storing dates as strings. Using the proper `DATE` data type avoids this problem of inconsistent formats, and it takes less space.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm. When I run the query via phpmyadmin directly, it works wonders. However, if I run it through php, not sure what happens. Any insight here?

Comment: @Akshay: if this is the SQL text sent to the database from PHP, it's going to return the same resultset as it does from other clients... a column named `tx_date`, the value returned for each row will be the result of the evaluation of the expression.

Comment: @Akshay "Not sure what happens" gives me no information. But as a complete guess, I think your code doesn't check for errors after submitting your query. If you check and report errors, you will probably find out you made a mistake in your SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many reasons you should always store date and datetime values in appropriate data types. `DATE_FORMAT()` is used to format a date value into a string, not convert an ambiguously formatted string from one format to another.

You'll need to create a much more complicated query to normalize your data. It will involve inspecting the current value, and then using something like `STR_TO_DATE` with an appropriate formatting string (determined by the aforementioned inspection results).

Comment: IMHO: this is a comment not an answer.